# structuring the firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a water quality monitoring web app using firebase. Each user will have different water quality data. So i'm confused how to structure the database in a way to link user with data. Should i use Firebase Authentication ? or should I create a node in db for users ?  If I use Firebase Authentication how to structure the database to link data unique to that particular user. There are questions similar to this in stackoverflow but the answers doesn't show any database structure and the answers are filled with android code. So I could'd understand.

Comment: Data modeling is a broad topic. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). Then do a few experiments and report back when/if you get stuck on a concrete problem.

Comment: I would also recommend you to read the [Firebase Documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) on how to use Firebase Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase authentication is how users identify themselves to Firebase and is not directly related to how the data is structured and stored within Firebase.

i.e you could set up Firebase to allow any unauthenticated person to read/write data or you could add authentication to create a secure environment where the data is stored.

You asked for a structure but there wasn't a whole lot of data in the question to go on so here's a possible solution assuming two authenticated users.

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Bill"
  uid_1
    name: "Jessup"

water_samples
   -Uijjsj99as9dad
      sampled_by: uid_0
      sample_result "Poor"
      datestamp: "070724"
   -Yi8j9ko90k9dsd
      sampled_by: uid_1
      sample_result "Good"
      datestamp: "070725"
```

note: the keys Uijjsj99as9dad and Yi8j9ko90k9dsd were created with childByAutoId (swift) or a push()

In this example, Bill sampled some water on July 24th and the result was poor. Whereas Jessup sampled it again on the 25th and the result was good.